# ¿Como almaceno un objeto en Session en Asp.net core Web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, session, asp.net-core, objeto

```
       //
      public class OrderVM
      {
       public User numUsu { get; set; } 
        //La lista es de ProductOrder
       public  List<ProductOrder> Products  {get; set;}

       }

        var orderView = new OrderVM();
        orderView.numUsu = new User();
        orderView.Products = new List<ProductOrder>();


              var productOrder = new ProductOrder
            {
                Code = prod,
                AplhaNumericCode = produ.AplhaNumericCode,
                Description = produ.Description,
                Name = produ.Name,
                WholesalePrice = produ.WholesalePrice,
                idProd=produ.idProd,
                quant = cant
            };

       orderView.Products.Add(productOrder);
```

Comment: Una recomendacion tambien al utilizar Session, es poder tener intellisense. Imaginate que debemos guardar con una clabe/key que es una cadena, para recuperarla o guardarla en otra lugar de la app tambien deberias tener "dicha cadena" y esto es susceptible a que el dev "se olvide" algun caracter, y es dificil de encontrar el problema. Por eso es bueno tener intellisense o armar algo asi con Session para Encapsular la llamada a la variable de Session

Answer (score 1):

Si te encuentas dentro de un `Controller` lo puedes hacer con el método `HttpContext.Session.Set<T>(key, data);`, suponiendo que deseamos agregar el objeto `orderView`:

```
string keyOrderView = "orderView";
HttpContext.Session.Set<OrderVM>(keyOrderView, orderView);
```

Ahora, para leer la información de esa variable de sesión es con el método `HttpContext.Session.Get<T>(key);`:

```
OrderVM ordenes = HttpContext.Session.Get<OrderVM>(keyOrderView);
```

En [este documento oficial de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state) (*en inglés*) se explica a detalle cómo manejar el estado y la sesión de la aplicación en ASP.NET Core.

Comment: +1 por el enlace a la documentacion. Muy importante ahora en ASP.NET Core que es modular, y Session esta en un paquete nuget [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/)